# django+mysql='DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database' error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've just installed `Python 3.3.0`, `mysql-connector` and `Django`. Then I created my first application called mysite. In `settings.py` I added these lines:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django', 
    'NAME': 'mydb',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
}
```

When I run the server and enter the admin page `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`, I see a long list of errors starting with `AttributeError at /admin/ 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'`. I do not know what to do with all this stuff. The full error description is:

```
AttributeError at /admin/
'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/admin/
 Django Version:    1.6.1
 Exception Type:    AttributeError
 Exception Value:   

 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

  Exception Location:   C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py in __exit__, line 86
  Python Executable:    C:\Python33\python.exe
  Python Version:   3.3.0
  Python Path:  

  ['C:\\mysite',
  'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python33.zip',
  'C:\\Python33\\DLLs',
  'C:\\Python33\\lib',
  'C:\\Python33',
  'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**EDIT**

When I run python manage.py syncdb, I also get a long list of errors:

```
C:\mysite>python manage.py syncdb
 Creating tables ...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
 399, in execute_from_command_line
 utility.execute()
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
 392, in execute
 self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv
 self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285,
 in execute
 output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415,
 in handle
 return self.handle_noargs(**options)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
 , line 96, in handle_noargs
 sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style, se
 en_models)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\creation.py", line 83,
 in sql_create_model
 model, f, known_models, style)
 TypeError: sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references() takes 4 positional arguments
 but 5 were given
```

Comment: have you tried running python manage.py syncdb?  if so did you go through the process of making the superuser?

Comment: Also, you should have some commandline tool installed, like CygWin.

Comment: Please, have a look at my post again. I added the list of errors that I got after running python manage.py syncdb

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251682/django-syncdb-works-in-sqlite-failing-in-mysql/21357079#21357079 for a solution. It's a fairly straightforward fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was experiencing exactly the same problem. There are lots of suggestions on how you can modify part of existing libraries to make Python3 work with MySQL, but I didn't find any of them to work 100%. I wasn't able to make official MySQL Python connector to work with Django and Python 3.3.

What did work was switching to PyMySQL library instead. Few months back I already tried it but it didn't work for me back then. Now, there is a new version, 0.6.1 which worked out of the box. So, few more details:

My environment: OSX 10.9 , Python 3.3.3, Django 1.6.1, MyPySQL 0.6.1, MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows

How to make it work:

1. Install PyMySQL version 0.6.1 (https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/): you can install it either by using pip, i.e. : `pip install PyMySQL` or by manually downloading the package; there is a good documentation on their website on how to do that.
2. Open your Django App **__init__.py** and paste the following lines:

   ```
   import pymysql
   pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
   ```
3. Now, open **settings.py** and make sure your DATABASE property looks like this:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'NAME': 'mydb',
          'USER': 'dbuser',
          'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
          'HOST': 'dbhost',
          'PORT': '3306'
       }
   }
   ```
4. That's it, you should be able to execute `python manage.py syncdb` so init your MySQL DB; see the sample output below:

   ```
   Creating tables ...
   Creating table django_admin_log
   Creating table auth_permission
   Creating table auth_group_permissions
   ...
   ...
   Creating table socialaccount_socialtoken

   You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error for Django 1.8.9, Python 3.6.12. And I was using `django-transaction-hooks==0.2`. And my DATABASES settings were

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    .
    .
```

I fixed the issue by using DATABASES settings as follows

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'transaction_hooks.backends.mysql',
    .
    .
```