# Django syncdb works in SQLite, failing in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm a newbie to MySQL, and haven't used Django for anything in production. I've been doing development under Windows 7 with SQLite, and am trying to move the code to a Linux server running MySQL.

When I ran syncdb, it created the first three tables then threw an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 96, in handle_noargs
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style, seen_models)
  File "/home/gsdemo01/project_file/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 83, in sql_create_model
    model, f, known_models, style)
TypeError: sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

The model immediately after the last one created is a Metaclass, followed by a class that inherits from it:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    # con = models.ForeignKey(Convention)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    scheduler = models.ForeignKey(GCUser, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Room(Location):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=100)
```

This works fine with SQLite, so it seems like it has to be either a problem with the python connector package or with MySQL itself.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:**

Through trial and error I've determined that the issue is definitely with the Foreign Key field. If I comment that out the table is created correctly. As far as I can tell the modification suggested by Yogesh matches what we already have in the code, so if anyone has any other suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the solution here for the benefit of future users who run into this. It took many hours on the part of my partner to ferret this out.

The simple part of the solution is to edit creation.py to change

```
def sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references (self, model, field, known_models, style):
```

to

```
def sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references (self, *args):
```

There's a routine with the same name and almost the same syntax in site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py, but you want the one in site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py.

You're not done yet, though, because the module gets copied to site-packages/mysql/connector/django/creation.py, and that doesn't happen automatically on edit, so you'll need to copy it over manually. I deleted the .pyc file for good measure, but that "shouldn't" have been necessary.

Of course, none of this should have been necessary...

Answer (score 0):

If you using these virsions Python3.3 Django1.6 use MySql official middleware mysql-connector-python-1.1.4-py3.3.

The solution:
find: creation.py within your site-packages and Modification method: sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references is: you can only modify the method parameters

```
def sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references (self, model, field, known_models, style):
```

This is not a good solution,this is alternate for remove error.

Comment: We are using all those versions. We changed the call as specified (though it used 'f' instead of 'field'). All that got us was "sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given"

Comment: python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py
replace def sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references (self, model, field, known_models, style):

Comment: I think I was looking in the wrong place before. This is what I have for that definition in my installation:

def sql_for_inline_foreign_key_references(self, model, field, known_models, style):

I don't see how that's different from what you're suggesting. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users using MacOSX 10.9 (aka Mavericks) or up, this solution works perfectly, but be sure you're going to the right place if you're using python3 to edit the *creation.py* file from the *mysql.connector*:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/creation.py
```

FYI:

> Environment: Python3 / Mysql-connector-1.1.4 / Django-1.6.1