# Can't save object using save() - AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have this class and I'm trying to create object by using shell:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    free_day = models.DateField(null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.person
```

```
p = Person.objects.get(username='Herehere')
t = Task(person=p,text='blabla')
t.save()
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'
```

If I change

```
person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
```

to

```
person = models.OneToOneField(Person, primary_key)
```

I got

```
'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'operators'
```

My settings.py db configurations:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'ldap': {
        'ENGINE': 'ldapdb.backends.ldap',
        'NAME': AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI,
        'USER': AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN,
        'PASSWORD': AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD,
    },
}
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908086/djangomysql-databasewrapper-object-has-no-attribute-database-error

Comment: I thought it was my db configuration at setting.py but I don't see if this cause the problem. I updated my post with settings.py.

Comment: Did you include the `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['ldapdb.router.Router']` ?

Comment: yes I did, still got the same problem :/
I don't have any clue what possible cause this